# Graphviz Library - Renderer Missing

Tags: graphviz

I'm using the Graphviz API in a project. EVereything is okay except that when I run the executable I get

> Error: renderer for png is unavailable

How do I go about solving this?

Comment: Graphviz version? Platform? Graphviz script & command line to reproduce? Do you use the API (Graphviz as a library) *or* do you call the executable? Do you mean by _executable_ your own executable using the library?

Comment: @marapet Thanks for the reply. Yes, i'm using it as a library under ubuntu, Graphviz v 2.28.

Comment: Wouldn't this question fit better on http://serverfault.com/ ?

Answer (score 0):

On CentOS there's a package called "graphviz-gd" which contains some plugin renderers. If you check in "/usr/lib/graphviz/config" what you see is this:

```
libgvplugin_gd.so.3 gd {
        render {
                gd 1
                gd2 1
                gif 1
                jpg 1
                jpeg 1
                png 1
                wbmp 1
        }
        render {
                vrml 1
        }
        textlayout {
                textlayout 2
        }
        loadimage {
                gif2gd 1
                jpeg2gd 1
                png2gd 1
                gif2ps 1
                jpeg2ps 1
                png2ps 1
        }
}
```

If you don't have that particular library, none of those features will work. Not sure about Ubuntu, probably a similar package name.